# How to use value in Application Settings load?

Tags: c#, configuration

```
    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }
```

> I used Application Settings and When
>   Form was load i see value in control
>   but i can't use its when Form load
>   event.
>
> how to use value that bind from
>   Application Settings when event
>   Form1_Load ?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

To access settings

> ```
> string a=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["someProperty"];
> ```

To save settings

```
        ExeConfigurationFileMap map=new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
        map.ExeConfigFilename=pathToYourConfigurationFile; //<-String
        Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(map,ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        config.AppSettings.Settings["someProperty"].Value = a;
        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full);
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```

I hope I understood your question right and this helps you.